# Root Object in Hibernate Root Validator Message Interpolator

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

I was trying some experiment with Message Interpolator feature provided in Bean Validation framework.

I want to access the Root object in it so that I can add properties from root in the message I want to build. I tried a lot but I could not get it. Just want to know if this is possible.

So far I have done.

```
Configuration<?> configuration = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure();
ValidatorFactory factory = configuration
    .messageInterpolator(new MessageInterpolator() {

            @Override
            public String interpolate(String string, MessageInterpolator.Context cntxt) {
                //implementation
                // Root Bean Here ??????
            }

            @Override
            public String interpolate(String string, MessageInterpolator.Context cntxt, Locale locale) {
                //implementation
            }
        })
    .buildValidatorFactory();

Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```

> Some pointers on how to achieve this would be really great, i.e some
>   how to add properties from Root bean in message along with current
>   invalid value.